# How to create Favorite button by List View In Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sharepoint-2010

I would like to create cinema app for that one module which is looking as cinema hall in a List view along with having a Favorite button. when user click that favorite button then current list view items all add into the another module of Favorite list view.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It's nice that you want to do that. But what is your question? (Remember, this is not a write-my-code-for-me website, so that's not a valid question)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to learn to implement a custom listView. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a great tutorial. Do this first.

Once you are done with creating the adapter and custom layout, do the following:

```
favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              // use sharedPreferences to store small data like strings and ids

              // if your data is big then write it into mysql database
        }
});
```

Tutorials on sharedpreferences: [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Tutorials on sqlite database: [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) & [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

When you are viewing the favorite listview, then simply read the data from your database and show it on the listview

Comment: Hi thank you your valuable response. I have already developed that code but when i click the my favorite button then on the next pages will looks as like empty. I mean no items are copying there? please help me on the same.

Comment: post your cinemaListView adapter codes and also the part where you read from database